# How to hook a vertex of a curve to a certain object?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to hook a curve vertex to an object and this method works perfectly:

```
bpy.ops.object.hook_add_selob(use_bone=False)
```

The problem is when I try to do this from python. I have to select the object, which can be done. But the operation seem to imply that the vertex is the active object or something? Is there a way around this in python or can I setup the hook directly via class-access bypassing the operation entirely?

[image]

I can see that it made a modifier on the curve. But I can't see how this modifier works only for the vertex. If I add a modifier manually and set the object as target, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the objects by name (names are unique), you can get them by global data access:

```
curve = bpy.data.objects["BezierCurve"]
hook = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
```

Or even better per *scene in context* if you'd like to turn this into an operator later on:

```
curve = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("BezierCurve")
hook = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Empty")
```

To add a modifier to an object, with its [name and type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new):

```
modifier = curve.modifiers.new("Hook", 'HOOK')
```

Then the modifier has its own specific attributes and methods

For hook, as [described here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.HookModifier.html#module-bpy.types):

The target object:

```
modifier.object = hook
```

And the hooked vertices. a bezier curve handle has 3 points, so you can set indices with:

```
handle_index = 0
index_from = 3 * handle_index
index_to = index_from + 3
modifier.vertex_indices_set( range(index_from, index_to) )
```

All together:

```
import bpy

curve = bpy.data.objects["BezierCurve"]
hook = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]

modifier = curve.modifiers.new("Hook", 'HOOK')
modifier.object = hook

handle_index = 0
index_from = 3 * handle_index
index_to = index_from + 3
modifier.vertex_indices_set( range(index_from, index_to) )
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you!