# EMPTY won't hook to lattice properly Blender API

Tags: modifiers, lattice

I am trying to hook my EMPTY to my lattice through the Blender API so when I move my EMPTY the lattice is deformed. As it is now when I run the code it shows that my EMPTY is connected to the center of the lattice which is not what I want.

If I were to do it through the `3D viewport` I would add my lattice and add my EMPTY. Then I would first select the EMPTY followed by the lattice. Enter edit mode and select all vertices of the lattice. Then `CTRL H` and `hook to selected object`.

```
collection = bpy.context.collection
lattice = bpy.data.lattices.new("Lattice")
lattice_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Lattice", lattice)
lattice_ob.scale = (224, 352, 224)
lattice_ob.location = (112, 176, 112)
lattice_ob.data.points_u = 5
lattice_ob.data.points_v = 5
lattice_ob.data.points_w = 5

bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(lattice_ob)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = lattice_ob
lattice_ob.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.lattice.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


for i in range(len(DIR7pointlist)):
    df = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(DIR7point, DIR7pointlist[i]), delimiter=',')
    for j in range(len(df)):
        xx, yy, zz = df[j]
        r = 5
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type = 'SPHERE', radius = r, location = (xx, yy, zz))
    break

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')

for ob in collection.objects:
    if ob.type == "EMPTY":
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = lattice_ob
        lattice_ob.select_set(True)
        ob.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        
        hookmod = lattice_ob.modifiers.new("Hook", 'HOOK')
        hookmod.falloff_radius = 1
        hookmod.falloff_type = 'SMOOTH'
        hookmod.object = ob
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to hook a vertex of a curve to a certain object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201717/how-to-hook-a-vertex-of-a-curve-to-a-certain-object)

```
modifier.vertex_indices_set( range(index_from, index_to) )
```